# Show changes in the TortoiseSVN log view shows unexpected result

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using the Log Messages view from a file in windows explorer.
The Log Messages view shows that this file has been committed to revision 666 and 668.

If I select both rev 666 and 668 right clicking the file in question in the bottom view, choosing Show changes; it shows that the file has 6 changes between the two revisions.

If I only select rev 668, right click the file in question in the bottom view, choosing Show changes; it shows that the file has 57 changes between revision 667 and 668.

If I show the log from the root of the repository it's apparent that the file in question was not committed in revision 667.

I've been under the impression that show changes on a single revision shows the last commit changes. How can it possibly be different to selecting two adjacent revisions?